# D3js: Dragging a group by using one of it's children

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drag-and-drop

Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6NBy2/

Code:

```
var in_editor_drag = d3.behavior.drag()
             .origin(function() {
                var g = this.parentNode;
                return {x: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[0],
                        y: d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate[1]};
            })
            .on("drag", function(d,i) {

                g = this.parentNode;
                translate = d3.transform(g.getAttribute("transform")).translate;
                x = d3.event.dx + translate[0],
                y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];
                d3.select(g).attr("transform", "translate(" + x + "," + y + ")");
                d3.event.sourceEvent.stopPropagation();
            });

svg = d3.select("svg");
d = {x: 20, y: 20 };
groups = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(20, 20)");

groups
    .append("rect")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .style("fill", "green")
        .call(in_editor_drag)
        .style("opacity", 0.4);
```

I'm trying to drag a group by using one of it's children as a handle. Simply, what i'm trying to do is, when a groups child is dragged:

- Get translation transformation of group
- Get drag distance from d3.event.dx, d3.event.dy
- Apply difference to group's transform attribute

When child dragged, group does not move as expected. It moves less than the dragged distance, and it begins to jump here and there.

What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit:**

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6NBy2/2/

I'm trying to drag the whole group by using one or more of it's children as dragging handles.

Comment: It actually works the same way if you attach the drag behaviour to the `g` element -- http://jsfiddle.net/6NBy2/1/

Comment: Yes, Lars, that was my answer below sometime ago. As I mentioned in my accompanying comment, if the intent is to drag a group, then the example should contain a group and not just one rectangle. Well, although a g is a group and perhaps that settles it :).

Comment: But come to think of it, is not the 'g' a misnomer here? It refers to the rectangle and not a true `g` element in SVG convention.

Comment: Thanks. But in implementation, groups will contain more than one child, such as text nodes, shapes etc. and the translation should be applied to whole group, to be able to translate all children at the same time. Therefore g=this does not address the issue. I will update the example.

Comment: I attached the call to the g group. It is working for me. It is not needed under the children but you can leave it there as well. Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nivaldo/28HRD/).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an old question, but not really answered. I had exactly the same problem and wanted to drag the group by only one child (not all child elements of the `<g>`).
The problem is, that the `d3.event.dx/y` is calculated relatively to the position of the `<g>`. And as soon as the `<g>` is moved by `.attr(“transform”, “translate(x, y)”)`, the `d3.event.dx/dy` is adjusted to the new (smaller) value. This results in a jerky movement with approx. the half of the speed of the cursor. I found two possible solutions for this:

**First (finally I ended up with this approach):**

Append the drag handle rect directly to the svg and not to the `<g>`. So it is positioned relatively to the `<svg>` and not to the `<g>`. Then move both (the `<rect>` and the `<g>`) within the on drag function.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var group = svg
    .append("g").attr("id", "group")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, 0)");
group
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .style("fill", "green")
    .style("opacity", 0.4);
group
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 5)
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "hanging")
    .text("drag me");
handle = svg
    .append("rect")
        .data([{
        // Position of the rectangle
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }]) 
    .attr("class", "draghandle")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .style("opacity", 0.4)
    .attr("cursor", "move")
    .call(d3.drag().on("drag", function (d) {
            console.log("yep");
            d.x += d3.event.dx;
            d.y += d3.event.dy;
            
            // Move handle rect
            d3.select(this)
                .attr("x", function (d) {
                    return d.x;
                })
                .attr("y", function (d) {
                    return d.y;
                });
            
            // Move Group
            d3.select("#group").attr("transform", "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")");
    }));
```

```html
<body>
    <svg width="400" height="400"></svg>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

**Second:**

Check on which element the cursor was during the drag event with `d3.event.sourceEvent.path[0]` and run the drag function only if the handle `<rect>` was clicked. With this approach, all elements can be grouped within one `<g>` (no need for an additional `<rect>` outside the group). The downside of this method is, that the drag is also executed, if the cursor is moved over the drag handle with mouse down.

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var group = svg
    .append("g")
    .data([{
        // Position of the rectangle
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }])
    .attr("id", "group")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")"
    })
    .call(d3.drag().on("drag", function (d) {
        if (d3.event.sourceEvent.target.classList.value === "draghandle") {
            console.log("yep");
            d.x += d3.event.dx;
            d.y += d3.event.dy;
            d3.select(this).attr("transform", function (d) {
                return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")"
            })
        } else {
            console.log("nope");
            return;
        }
    }));
group
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .style("fill", "green")
    .style("opacity", 0.4);
group
    .append("text")
    .attr("x", 10)
    .attr("y", 5)
    .attr("dominant-baseline", "hanging")
    .text("drag me");
handle = group
    .append("rect")
    .attr("class", "draghandle")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .style("fill", "blue")
    .style("opacity", 0.4)
    .attr("cursor", "move");
```

```html
<body>
    <svg width="400" height="400"></svg>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `drag.container()` to set the container accessor.

See [the D3 docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-drag#drag_container).

Answer (score 0):

use `g = this;` instead of `g = this.parentNode;`

Comment: But I realize that this does not address your intent to drag a group of nodes; perhaps it will help if you were to post an example where there is a group of rectangles and not just one? Or some example more akin to what you want.

Comment: So basically rectangle is acting as a svg group element right (based on original posters question)??