# SVG <g> element dragging causes flickering issue using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, drag-and-drop

I have been trying to use d3 library for drag n drop of dvg  element by using transform translate. I am able to drag an element but it flickers while dragging.

I have been searching and doing trial and error so far from below links but it doesn't help me.

["Stuttering" drag when using d3.behavior.drag() and transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078535/stuttering-drag-when-using-d3-behavior-drag-and-transform)

[D3.js: Dragging everything in group ('g') by element contained in the group using origin() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30132344/d3-js-dragging-everything-in-group-g-by-element-contained-in-the-group-usin)

[How to drag an svg group using d3.js drag behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15943292/how-to-drag-an-svg-group-using-d3-js-drag-behavior#answers)

For the last link, I think I am not able to understand the necessity of svg structure for this requirement which causes this issue. Can anyone help me here?

Comment: I am not familiar with d3 library, but I noticed that your dragged function parameter sometimes receives undefined as a parameter, which is causing it to flick. You can start by checking that .on("drag", dragged) is called from the correct location and it passes the correct parameters data to the callback.

Comment: However, I'm new in D3 and I'm not sure about that but that parameter has not been used in the function.I tried removing it but no luck

Comment: I have posted the cause and a solution for this Problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45817005/3620572).

Comment: @roland: Out of my curiosity, doesn't it possible without appending anything into dragging object or just changing the structure of my svg? The reason of this requirement is that I am dealing with large svg and I dont want to add anyting from javascript if possible

Comment: @DipeshRaichana: Have you tried the second Approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easier to use `d3.event` instead of `d3.mouse` for this. Here is a d3 style approach with `.data()`:

1. Read out the `translate` attribute of the `<g>` in your source svg.
2. Add the x and y value of the `translate` to the `data` of the d3 object.
3. Adjust the `data` and the `translate` of the `<g>` during the drag event.

```js
function bindDragging() {

    // Define d3 object
    var g = d3.select("#group");

    // Get translate (from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38230545/3620572)
    var elem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    elem.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", g.attr("transform"));
    var matrix = elem.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix;
    var x = matrix.e;
    var y = matrix.f;

    g.data([{
        // Position of the group
        x: x,
        y: y
        }])
        .call(d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragend)
        );

    function dragstarted(d) {
        g.selectAll("rect").classed("active", true);
    }

    function dragged(d) {
        // Set the new position
        d.x += d3.event.dx;
        d.y += d3.event.dy;
        d3.select(this).attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + [d.x, d.y] + ")"
        });

    }

    function dragend(d) {
        g.selectAll("rect").classed("active", false);
    }
}
bindDragging();
```

```css
#group {
    stroke-width: 3;
    stroke: #808080;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    cursor: grab;
}

.active {
    stroke: #ff0000;
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
    cursor: grabbing;
}
```

```html
<div class="svgContainer">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 776.63 680.09">
    <g id="group" transform="translate(0, 0)">
        <rect width="100" height="50" style="fill:rgb(40, 40, 109);" />
        <rect width="100" height="50" y="50" style="fill:rgb(63, 149, 75);" />
    </g>
</svg>
</div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for this. I would kindly like to request you to share thought process behind it. I mean, what was the issue in my code and how did you figure it out(It would really grateful if you can answer)?

Comment: @DipeshRaichana: You are welcome. This is just how D3.js is intended to be used. You did something odd with the x and y variables. It is best practice to bind the data to D3-objects (D3 = Data-Driven Documents). First you have to read the data (in this case the x and y of transform) from the given svg. Then this data are bound to the D3-object (of the `<g>`). And now you can use this data for the translocation. BTW the JavaScript could be even shorter.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation. I am using D3 because there are more functionalities than just Drag n Drop with SVG(I searched and came to know that svg animations cannot work with jquery).